# Spring Data JPA How to deal with Date arithmatic?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Following is my repository method:

```
@Query("Select AVG(ipe.executionFinishTime-ipe.executionStartTime) from IPExecution ipe where ipe.integrationProcessID=:integrationProcessID")
Date findAvarageExecutionTime(@Param("integrationProcessID")Long integrationProcessID);
```

when I execute the above method it is throwing the below exception,

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type double : 00:00:09.266826
```

Can someone point me for documentation related to handling date in spring data jpa?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA or JPA. The SQL AVG function doesn't work for dates. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html